# App Testing iOS Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, libxml2

Well, I have looked through a lot of questions with the several problem, but one of them was helpful.

I am using Pods and everything runs well, when I run the project and try it out on my device - it runs perfectly, but when I do testing, it says an error.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlreader.h:13:10:
>   'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found Could not build Objective-C
>   module 'libxml2'

"libxml2" that I'm using is running fine in my project, my app is fully functional, but then I do the "testing" then it collapses.

I did add /usr/include/libxml2 to the Search Path header in Build Settings. Changed scheme and did clean & build and then change back. Tried re-installing/updating pods. Then deleted the DerivedData folder in `~Developer/Xcode/`

but still no luck at all

I have struggled on this problem for several hours now...

Suggestions?